# Make custom Airflow macros expand other macros

Tags: airflow

Is there any way to make a user-defined macro in Airflow which is itself computed from other macros?

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

dag = DAG(
    'simple',
    schedule_interval='0 21 * * *',
    user_defined_macros={
        'next_execution_date': '{{ dag.following_schedule(execution_date) }}',
    },
)

task = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_op',
    bash_command='echo "{{ next_execution_date }}"',
    dag=dag,
)
```

The use case here is to back-port the new Airflow v1.8 `next_execution_date` macro to work in Airflow v1.7. Unfortunately, this template is rendered without macro expansion:

```
$ airflow render simple bash_op 2017-08-09 21:00:00
    # ----------------------------------------------------------
    # property: bash_command
    # ----------------------------------------------------------
    echo "{{ dag.following_schedule(execution_date) }}"
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here are some solutions:

### 1. Override `BashOperator` to add some values to the context

```
class NextExecutionDateAwareBashOperator(BashOperator):
    def render_template(self, attr, content, context):
        dag = context['dag']
        execution_date = context['execution_date']
        context['next_execution_date'] = dag.following_schedule(execution_date)

        return super().render_templates(attr, content, context)
        # or in python 2:
        # return super(NextExecutionDateAwareBashOperator, self).render_templates(attr, content, context)
```

The good part with this approach: you can capture some repeated code in your custom operator.

The bad part: you have to write a custom operator to add values to the context, before templated fields are rendered.

### 2. Do your computation in a user defined macro

[Macros](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#macros) are not necessarily values. They can be functions.

In your dag :

```
def compute_next_execution_date(dag, execution_date):
    return dag.following_schedule(execution_date)

dag = DAG(
    'simple',
    schedule_interval='0 21 * * *',
    user_defined_macros={
        'next_execution_date': compute_next_execution_date,
    },
)

task = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_op',
    bash_command='echo "{{ next_execution_date(dag, execution_date) }}"',
    dag=dag,
)
```

The good part: you can define reusable functions to process values available at runtime ([XCom values](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms), job instance properties, task instance properties, etc...), and make your function result available to render a template.

The bad part (but not that annoying): you have to import such a function as a user defined macro in every dag where needed.

### 3. Call your statement directly in your template

This solution is the simplest (as mentioned by [Ardan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45941551/3216318)), and probably the good one in your case.

```
BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_op',
    bash_command='echo "{{ dag.following_schedule(execution_date) }}"',
    dag=dag,
)
```

Ideal for simple calls like this one. And they are some other objects directly available as [macros](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#macros) (like `task`, `task_instance`, etc...); even some standard modules are available (like `macros.time`, ...).

Comment: in first code snippet update last row, please 
`return super(NextExecutionDateAwareBashOperator, self).render_template(attr, content, context)`

Comment: @RomanKazakov: I think you're right when working with python 2; however I could use `super()` in python 3

Comment: @Géraud Can you please have a look at my question? You will help me if you can answer it. thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631581/how-to-use-xcom-pull-with-postgres-operator-airflow-2-0-2

Answer (score 9):

I would vote for making Airflow Plugin to inject your pre-defined macros.
Using this method, you can use your pre-defined macro in any Operator without declare anything.

Below are some custom macros that we're using.
Example using:  `{{ macros.dagtz_next_execution_date(ti) }}`

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.models import DagRun
import pendulum


@provide_session
def _get_dag_run(ti, session=None):
    """Get DagRun obj of the TaskInstance ti

    Args:
        ti (TYPE): the TaskInstance object
        session (None, optional): Not in use

    Returns:
        DagRun obj: the DagRun obj of the TaskInstance ti
    """
    task = ti.task
    dag_run = None
    if hasattr(task, 'dag'):
        dag_run = (
            session.query(DagRun)
            .filter_by(
                dag_id=task.dag.dag_id,
                execution_date=ti.execution_date)
            .first()
        )
        session.expunge_all()
        session.commit()
    return dag_run


def ds_add_no_dash(ds, days):
    """
    Add or subtract days from a YYYYMMDD
    :param ds: anchor date in ``YYYYMMDD`` format to add to
    :type ds: str
    :param days: number of days to add to the ds, you can use negative values
    :type days: int
    >>> ds_add('20150101', 5)
    '20150106'
    >>> ds_add('20150106', -5)
    '20150101'
    """

    ds = datetime.strptime(ds, '%Y%m%d')
    if days:
        ds = ds + timedelta(days)
    return ds.isoformat()[:10].replace('-', '')


def dagtz_execution_date(ti):
    """get the TaskInstance execution date (in DAG timezone) in pendulum obj

    Args:
        ti (TaskInstance): the TaskInstance object

    Returns:
        pendulum obj: execution_date in pendulum object (in DAG tz)
    """
    execution_date_pdl = pendulum.instance(ti.execution_date)
    dagtz_execution_date_pdl = execution_date_pdl.in_timezone(ti.task.dag.timezone)
    return dagtz_execution_date_pdl


def dagtz_next_execution_date(ti):
    """get the TaskInstance next execution date (in DAG timezone) in pendulum obj

    Args:
        ti (TaskInstance): the TaskInstance object

    Returns:
        pendulum obj: next execution_date in pendulum object (in DAG tz)
    """

    # For manually triggered dagruns that aren't run on a schedule, next/previous
    # schedule dates don't make sense, and should be set to execution date for
    # consistency with how execution_date is set for manually triggered tasks, i.e.
    # triggered_date == execution_date.
    dag_run = _get_dag_run(ti)
    if dag_run and dag_run.external_trigger:
        next_execution_date = ti.execution_date
    else:
        next_execution_date = ti.task.dag.following_schedule(ti.execution_date)

    next_execution_date_pdl = pendulum.instance(next_execution_date)
    dagtz_next_execution_date_pdl = next_execution_date_pdl.in_timezone(ti.task.dag.timezone)
    return dagtz_next_execution_date_pdl


def dagtz_next_ds(ti):
    """get the TaskInstance next execution date (in DAG timezone) in YYYY-MM-DD string
    """
    dagtz_next_execution_date_pdl = dagtz_next_execution_date(ti)
    return dagtz_next_execution_date_pdl.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


def dagtz_next_ds_nodash(ti):
    """get the TaskInstance next execution date (in DAG timezone) in YYYYMMDD string
    """
    dagtz_next_ds_str = dagtz_next_ds(ti)
    return dagtz_next_ds_str.replace('-', '')


def dagtz_prev_execution_date(ti):
    """get the TaskInstance previous execution date (in DAG timezone) in pendulum obj

    Args:
        ti (TaskInstance): the TaskInstance object

    Returns:
        pendulum obj: previous execution_date in pendulum object (in DAG tz)
    """

    # For manually triggered dagruns that aren't run on a schedule, next/previous
    # schedule dates don't make sense, and should be set to execution date for
    # consistency with how execution_date is set for manually triggered tasks, i.e.
    # triggered_date == execution_date.
    dag_run = _get_dag_run(ti)
    if dag_run and dag_run.external_trigger:
        prev_execution_date = ti.execution_date
    else:
        prev_execution_date = ti.task.dag.previous_schedule(ti.execution_date)

    prev_execution_date_pdl = pendulum.instance(prev_execution_date)
    dagtz_prev_execution_date_pdl = prev_execution_date_pdl.in_timezone(ti.task.dag.timezone)
    return dagtz_prev_execution_date_pdl


def dagtz_prev_ds(ti):
    """get the TaskInstance prev execution date (in DAG timezone) in YYYY-MM-DD string
    """
    dagtz_prev_execution_date_pdl = dagtz_prev_execution_date(ti)
    return dagtz_prev_execution_date_pdl.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


def dagtz_prev_ds_nodash(ti):
    """get the TaskInstance prev execution date (in DAG timezone) in YYYYMMDD string
    """
    dagtz_prev_ds_str = dagtz_prev_ds(ti)
    return dagtz_prev_ds_str.replace('-', '')


# Defining the plugin class
class AirflowTestPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "custom_macros"
    macros = [dagtz_execution_date, ds_add_no_dash,
              dagtz_next_execution_date, dagtz_next_ds, dagtz_next_ds_nodash,
              dagtz_prev_execution_date, dagtz_prev_ds, dagtz_prev_ds_nodash]
```

Comment: Interesting @z1k, and thanks for including the full code. It would be even better if you would trim down the many lines of Python into a minimum example to illustrate your point. Future readers and I will thank you for it 

Comment: @z1k  How do you use custom macros in operators or in DAG? Can you please show an example

Answer (score 5):

`user_defined_macros` are not processed as templates by default. If you want to keep a template in a `user_defined_macro` (or if you use a template in a `params` variable), you can always re-run the templating function manually:

```
class DoubleTemplatedBashOperator(BashOperator):
    def pre_execute(self, context):
        context['ti'].render_templates()
```

And this will work for templates that don't also reference other parameters or UDMs. This way, you can have "two-deep" templates.

Or put your UDM directly in the `BashOperator`'s command instead (the easiest solution):

```
BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_op',
    bash_command='echo "{{ dag.following_schedule(execution_date) }}"',
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: Yes, expanding the UDF macro into every place which needs it would definitely work, but then you repeat the same piece of macro code multiple times. I guess one could rely on Python facilities and instead of using a UDF macro, format strings at runtime: `bash_command='echo "{next_execution_date}"'.format(next_execution_date=NEXT_EXECUTION_DATE),` but it would not be as clean.

Comment: @mksios I tried to make my explanation clearer, but you can do exactly what you wanted to if you call `render_templates` before the task runs. By default your UDM gets put into the command; the second, manual time the template variables in the UDM get filled in.

Comment: I see, this is pretty cool... The only undesirable side effects of double-expansion I can think of are: (1) needing to escape any other part of the parameter to prevent double-expansion in parts where it is not desired; (2) having to do this in every operator type. Nevertheless, it seems closest to accomplishing the end goal... Time for a pull request to Airflow!

Comment: @mksios Great! Please upvote/accept the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

None of these was working for me so heres what I did, I used the `user_defined_macros` but I pass all template variables to my macro and then I use jinja to render the result

```
MACRO_CONFIG = 'config({"data_interval_start": data_interval_start, "data_interval_end": data_interval_end, "ds": ds, "ds_nodash": ds_nodash, "ts": ts, "ts_nodash_with_tz": ts_nodash_with_tz, "ts_nodash": ts_nodash, "prev_data_interval_start_success": prev_data_interval_start_success, "prev_data_interval_end_success": prev_data_interval_end_success, "dag": dag, "task": task, "macros": macros, "task_instance": task_instance, "ti": ti, "params": params, "conn": conn, "task_instance_key_str": task_instance_key_str, "conf": conf, "run_id": run_id, "dag_run": dag_run, "test_mode": test_mode})'

def config_macro(context):
    return FunctionThatReturnsTemplates(context)

with DAG(
        'my-dag-id',
        schedule_interval=None,
        start_date=days_ago(1),
        user_defined_macros={'config': config_macro}
) as dag:
...

def config_macro_template(attr_name):
    return '{{' + MACRO_CONFIG + '.' + attr_name + '}}'

class FunctionThatReturnsTemplates(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, name)

        logging.info('attr')
        logging.info(attr)
        logging.info("type(attr)")
        logging.info(type(attr))

        if callable(attr):
            logging.info('method attr')

            def render_result(*args, **kwargs):
                logging.info('before calling %s' % attr.__name__)
                result = attr(*args, **kwargs)
                logging.info('done calling %s' % attr.__name__)

                return Template(result).render(**self.context) if isinstance(result, str) or isinstance(result, unicode) else result

            return render_result

        logging.info('attr is not method')
        if isinstance(attr, str) or isinstance(attr, unicode):
            logging.info('attr is string or unicode')
            result = Template(attr).render(**self.context)
            logging.info(result)
            logging.info("result")
            return result

        return attr

    def __init__(self, context):
        logging.info('from sampling pipeline context')
        logging.info(context)
        self.context = context
...

    my_task = SomeOperator(
        templated_field=config_macro_template('function(args)'),
        task_id='my-task-id'
    )
```