# templated destination_dataset_table arg of one BigQueryOperator as templated From of another

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I'm trying to chain together a bunch of BigQuery SQL commands in a ETL pipeline where some of the outputs and inputs will be timestamped.

```
from datetime import timedelta
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator

DAG_NAME = 'foo'

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(7),
    'email': ['xxx@xxx.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="blah",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    template_searchpath=["/usr/local/airflow/dags/xxx/sql"])


GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID = 'xxx'
DATASET_ID = 'xxx'
first_output = GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID + ":" + DATASET_ID + "." + "first_output_" + '{{ ds_nodash }}'
second_output = GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID + ":" + DATASET_ID + "." + "second_output"
GOOGLE_CLOUD_PLATFORM_CONNECTION_ID="google_cloud_default"


first_op = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='first_output',
    dag=dag,
    bigquery_conn_id=GOOGLE_CLOUD_PLATFORM_CONNECTION_ID,
    bql="XXX.sql",
    use_legacy_sql=True,
    allow_large_results=True,
    destination_dataset_table=first_output # {{ ds }} gets substituted because destination_dataset_table is a templated field
)

second_op = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='second_op',
    dag=dag,
    bigquery_conn_id=GOOGLE_CLOUD_PLATFORM_CONNECTION_ID,
    bql="XXX_two.sql", # XXX_two.sql contains a {{ params.input_table }} reference
    params={'input_table': first_op.destination_dataset_table},
    use_legacy_sql=True,
    allow_large_results=True,
    destination_dataset_table=second_output

)

second_op.set_upstream(first_op)
```

Contents of XXX_two.sql:

```
SELECT * FROM [{{ params.input_table }}
```

Testing via:

```
airflow test blah second_op  2015-06-01
```

My current error is (in production as well)

```
Exception: BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {'reason': 'invalid', 'location': BLAH, 'message': 'Invalid table name: xxx:xx.first_output_{{ ds_nodash }}'}.
```

How can I access a templated field outside of the execution of the operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the templated table name, that is not rendered, as a param to the second_op.

Value of `first_op.destination_dataset_table` is assigned to `input_table` before [render_templates](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/models.py#L1617) gets called on the task_instance `first_op`.  When the bql is rendered in `second_op` it only translates the value of the param and hence returns:

```
SELECT * FROM xxx:xx.first_output_{{ ds_nodash }}
```

It works if you convert bql as a string, eg:

```
    BigQueryOperator(task_id='second_op',...,
                     bql='SELECT * FROM [{table}]'.format(table=first_op.destination_dataset_table)
```

and set first_output as mentioned by @tobi6.

This may not a feasible solution unless your SQL is as small as the example or you are willing to have the SQL live somewhere within the DAG file.

**EDIT:**

Since you add the temaplate_searchpath in the definition of the DAG, you can update the `XXX_two.sql` as the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [{{ params.input_table }}_{{ ds_nodash }}]
```

This allows you to pass the table name from the previous operation but leaves the task of rendering the BQ table partition to Airflow operator. If each of the operators/task_instance is called from the same DAG, this would solve your problem.

You can update to:

```
first_ouput = GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID + ":" + DATASET_ID + "." + "first_output"
first_op = BigQueryOperator(...,destination_dataset_table= "{}_{{{{ ds_nodash }}}}".format(first_ouput))
second_op = BigQueryOperator(..., params={'input_table': first_output},...
```

Comment: Great suggestion. Unfortunately I'd like my SQL to live outside of a python string (it's quite big).

Answer (score 4):

The field `destination_dataset_table` is definitely templated, as can be seen [in the source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-9-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py#L57) (of 1.9, no version was provided so I took the newest one):

```
template_fields = ('bql', 'destination_dataset_table')
```

I would change creating the string to:

```
first_output = "[{project}:{dataset}.first_output_{{{{ ds_nodash }}}}]".format(
    project=GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
    dataset=DATASET_ID)
```

The four curly braces should become two and the resulting string should look like

```
[my_project:my_dataset.first_output_{{ ds_nodash }}]
```

Now `ds_nodash` should be parsed when used in `destination_dataset_table`.

Note that I have also added the needed brackets `[ ]` for legacy statements. I am not sure if this might be connected to missing brackets as well.

**EDIT**

As @mask correctly stated, you are using the string from `first_op` in `second_op` `params` which I haven't seen in the beginning.

This is not working because of those reasons:

- first_op should not provide the string but you should use `first_output` - I am still wondering why this is working in the first place
- If you are pulling a string from a task you *won't* get the rendered string but always the raw, template string *if you are not making sure the fields have been processed (as mentioned by Mask)
- `params` is simply not templated and hence will not be updated correctly

Those are the solutions I can think of:

- Derive your own `BigDataOperator` and add `params` to templated fields (if that works b/c it is a dict)
- Or extend the `xxx_two.sql` so that it will not use `params.input_table` but also `first_output`. Since you want `first_output` to be available within templates you must first add it to the DAG param `user_defined_macros`.

To see more about those solutions, check out this related question: [Make custom Airflow macros expand other macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855949/make-custom-airflow-macros-expand-other-macros)

Comment: Sorry for forgetting the version. I am on 1.9.0.

Comment: Follow up question. Working in a console. Should I be able to create the first_op object and THEN immediately access destination_dataset_table and see the template filled in? Basically I'm wondering when the template actually gets rendered? During the __init__ phase of object creation or during execution?

Comment: I'm well aware of accepting answers. While both have been useful neither has solved my issue hence why the question is still open.

Comment: The both answers were in what way helpful? Are you still receiving the same error message after making proposed changes?

Comment: @Yurci SimonD confirmed that he is able to access a templated member variable outside of execution and Tobi6 confirmed that destination_dataset_table  is a templated field. And yes using their suggestions I am still receiving the same error. That's why I said it did not solve my issue and I have left the issue open.

Comment: In the error it says 'Invalid table name: xxx:xx.first_output_{{ ds_nodash }}', what is the actual table name?

Comment: @AndrewCassidy Updated my answer after some input from Mask

Comment: @tobi6: I am not sure if -  `...pulling a string from a task you won't get the rendered string but always the raw, template string` is necessarily true. You can pull the rendered string if you ensure you access it after task_instance.render_templates is called.  Eg: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1735027 works fine

Comment: @Mask Thank you, I didn't know that. Added some more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely reference the macros from outside the operator like you are doing, I'm doing this is some of my workflows.

Have you tried changing to:

```
first_output = GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID + ":" + DATASET_ID + "." + "first_output_{{ ds_nodash }}"
```

Perhaps JINJA doesn't like the concatenation of strings with different quotes?

Comment: any chance you could post a short complete working example of accessing the class member variable and it returning templated?