# Airflow: How can use macros to get the first day of last month?

Tags: airflow

I am trying to backfill a job that requires the date to be tuned to the first day of last month.

I could use:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

date = (date.today().replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1)
```

But I am not sure if the backfill in Airflow will return date.today() as the day of the run.

Answer (score 5):

I got to this which still spits out a timestamp, would need to add some string formatting to get just a date if that's what you need

```
dag = DAG('test',default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily')

def test_print(input):
    print('Testing')
    print(input)

test_print = PythonOperator(
        task_id='test_print',
        python_callable=test_print,
        op_args=['{{ execution_date + macros.dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=-1, day=1) }}'],
        dag=dag
)
```

Note the mix of relative and absolute arguments to [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html)

> year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond:Absolute information (argument is singular); adding or subtracting a
> relativedelta with absolute information does not perform an arithmetic
> operation, but rather REPLACES the corresponding value in the
> original datetime with the value(s) in relativedelta.

Answer (score 2):

Airflow has no influence on the `date.today()` function.

In fact, if you use this approach you remove one of Airflows greatest functions - restartability at any given date.

There is no macro that I know of to get the first day of last month. You could put your calculation function into a small function though - and use `context['taskinstance']['execution_date']` and not `date.today()`. See more macros here https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#macros

When you have a small function which returns the wanted value, you can add it as your own macro. See more on that in this question: [Make custom Airflow macros expand other macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855949/make-custom-airflow-macros-expand-other-macros)

**EDIT**

You have tried this:

```
LAST_MONTH = '{{ (execution_date.replace(day=1) - macros.timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1) }}'
```

It is not possible to use standard Python functions within Jinja template strings. Again, I suggest you build a function with one parameter, date, which returns a date as you need it. Then add this function to the available macros with the DAG property `user_defined_macros` and use this function like `LAST_MONTH = {{ my_date_function_which_gives_my_needed_date(execution_date) }}`

More, as stated already, in both links, which also have step-by-step help.

Comment: I put it as: LAST_MONTH = '{{ (execution_date.replace(day=1) - macros.timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1) }}'


But it seem to give me an error...

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error. It is not possible to help if the only info we have is *seems to give me an error*.

Comment: Why do you fill a variable? Please edit your question and add the DAG code. Which kind of operator do you use?