# How to recursively evaluate an Airflow macro {{ ds }} passed into DAG params

Tags: airflow, jinja2, mwaa

We have an Airflow DAG to extract some data from a database table. It usually extracts data a day at a time and exports to another system.  The DAG is scheduled `@daily` and extracts data for the given logical date `{{ ds }}` using a SQL WHERE clause like

`WHERE date BETWEEN '{{ ds }}' AND '{{ ds }}'`

This is working fine when the DAG is scheduled by Airflow.

When performing backfill operations, we would like to be able to manually trigger the DAG to extract a wider date range by supplying a DAG parameter and using it in the WHERE clause like:

`WHERE date BETWEEN '{{ params.start_date }}' AND '{{ ds }}'`

The `Trigger DAG w/ config` function in the Airflow UI can be used to accomplish this.

We need the SQL to work for daily "day-at-a-time" and backfill operations.

During a scheduled run, the `start_date` parameter defaults to:

```
{
   "start_date": "{{ ds }}",
   "start_date_alt": "ds"
}
```

and when we manually trigger a backfill, a static date would be supplied e.g.

```
{
    "start_date": "2023-01-01",
    "start_date_alt": "2023-01-01"
}
```

This contrived DAG example illustrates the issue with a simple `BashOperator`, but in our real world use case, it is a `GlueJobOperator`.

For a manually triggered run, the output from the `BashOperator` in the example is:

`Extracting data from 2023-01-01 2023-01-01 to 2023-10-28` which is what we intend.

However for a scheduled DAG run, the output from the `BashOperator` is:

`Extracting data from {{ ds }} ds to 2023-10-27` which is not what we indented, we need it to be e.g.

`Extracting data from 2023-10-28 2023-10-28 to 2023-10-28`

The issue seems to be that the value returned by `{{ params.start_date }}` is itself another jinja template which needs to be evaluated, but this is not happening.

I have tried removing the braces in `params.start_date_alt` to see if that fixes the issue, but it doesn't.

How can we get the value returned by `{{ params.start_date }}` to be evaluated as a jinja template when passed to the `BashOperator`?

```py
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    "start_date": datetime(2023, 9, 1),
}

with DAG(
    dag_id=f"recursive-template",
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    params={
        "start_date": "{{ ds }}",
        "start_date_alt": "ds"
    }
) as dag:
    bash_task = BashOperator(
        task_id="echo_dates",
        bash_command="echo Extracting data from {{ params.start_date }} {{ params.start_date_alt }} to {{ ds }}"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have *a* solution/work-around which is to ensure that templates are rendered twice by adding a `pre_execute` hook to the `BashOperator`.  Thanks to [ardan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3677696/ardan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45941551/5546477) to [Make custom Airflow macros expand other macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855949/make-custom-airflow-macros-expand-other-macros)
Perhaps there's another way of ding this?

```py
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    "start_date": datetime(2023, 9, 1),
}

def pre_execute(context):
    # Render templates twice, once here, the other occurring within the execute() method of the operator.
    context['ti'].render_templates()

with DAG(
    dag_id=f"recursive-template",
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    params={
        "start_date": "{{ ds }}"
    },
) as dag:
    bash_task = BashOperator(
        task_id="echo_dates",
        bash_command="echo Extracting data from {{ params.start_date }} to {{ ds }}",
        pre_execute=pre_execute
    )
```